# Magnetic connector for LED light on tent mesh

Tags: tents, electronic-gear

I'm looking at extending a strip of LED lighting into another of the tents rooms.
Dividing the rooms is mozzie mesh.
I could run a 3m extension wire down and back up again, however, I was wondering if there was some sort of connector that would magnetically clamp to either side of the mesh and form the electrical connection to extend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know of anything off the shelf that is a magnetic connector but there is a thing called a “cable pass-through” or “cable gland” that you could use to pierce the netting and pass your cable through while sealing it from insects.  Go to an electricians shop and describe what you’re up to.  Alternatively if you don’t mind ugly, you could hand stitch or glue a patch of camp mattress foam into the netting with a slit in it that would allow you to push your wire through while keeping out the bugs.

[image]